# Best XLR cable and metal for home use & vocals?

Tags: cables, microphone, sound, metal, xlr

I am very lost on what the recommended XLR and also the what the recommended type of metal connector is for sound quality as many say completely different things such as Silver being more conductive and more transparent with Gold being more durable and warm sounding etc? I only record at home in a small room with only my voice so I am lost on what to go for? Copper, Silver, Gold, Platinum or other or a hybrid of sorts?

My current cable is a LyxPro Balanced Gold XLR Cable.

My microphone is an sE X1 S which has a gold connector on it if that info is any of relevance?

*Edit* I also almost never unplug my XLR cables if that is also any of relevance?

Comment: Most here would say a cable is a cable, and expensive cables are a marketing thing.

Comment: The word "best" is an invitation for trouble. What are your requirements? A component that meets those requirements is adequate. A component that exceeds those requirements is overkill. If you have an endless budget, feel free to overkill. Asking what item is "best" without stating requirements is not possible to answer (or is a subjective debate, which is off-topic).

Comment: If this is "more warm sounding" then wouldn't that suggest to you that is altering and therefore distorting the signal?

Comment: I once worked for a pro audio company, wiring up studio desks. Even the fanciest systems were interconnected with thin simple balanced cable, perhaps 2 x 22 awg, tinned 7 strands, red/green PVC insulation. It had an aluminium foil screen with a ground wire. Not for flexing of course. All of your sound will pass through one of these at some point...

Answer (score 2):

This is all marketing bullshit meant to confuse you. As a plain customer, you cannot evaluate the thickness or durability of the contact plating anyways.

What's important for microphone and other pickup cabling is the mechanical stability of the connectors. Both the contacts and the housing, so you don't pick up noise from the contacts as they move. XLR is much better than other connector types in this regard already, but I have to assume there are also cheap types out there. Most likely those covered in 0.5µm gold.

Contact plating is your least concern. Nickel is ok. The cheap gold plating on "high end" connectors is scratched off from the contacts anyways as soon you plug them in, exposing the nickel undercoating.

Comment: Good point about the gold thickness.  Gold platings of up to 0.5 um thickness are only intended for "static" contact applications - mate one time.  For repeated mate/demate cycles, gold should be at least 1.25 um thick, with 2.5 um recommended for high wear applications.  I would be surprised if the OP's mic connector comes anywhere near close to this.

Comment: And agree about this being marketing BS.  Right in the line with "cryogenically cooled, phase stabilized" speaker cables.

Answer (score 1):

The interconnects inside devices are copper anyway. Any standard cable is good enough for audio frequencies if it has good enough quality connectors and cable. Having silver in your connectors won't affect at audio frequencies in any way that humans can hear, and does not make your audio warm and fuzzy. If it does, then the cable is clearly causing distortion. Most yellow connectors may not be gold but some bronze alloy. Again, good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Gold is useful for preventing corrosion on copper contacts. Generally the point of such cables is to have a long useful life in a variety of conditions. If you're a touring musician, the cables will be subjected to wide temperatures, humidity (beer and soda!), and physical abuse. The "best" cable is one that is well constructed, has durable connectors, and yes, a corrosion-resistant plating can help prevent problems due to contamination or corrosion on the plugs and sockets. But coatings can be physically worn off and scratched. Don't place too much value on precious metal coating...

There are vast amounts of "audio foolery" (aka "marketing wank") out there. Most companies want you to believe that their cables are best. It's only fair in a competitive market. However, pseudoscience and irrelevant jargon are sometimes employed (along with massive price increases). Thanks to the placebo effect and various cognitive biases, people can actually think such products are better, thus perpetuating myths and rip-offs.

As long as the signal gets to the next device in the chain without perceptible modifications or losses that exceed the noise floor or transformative nature of said device, it's sufficient. In other words, you will see a much larger difference changing amplifiers than you will changing conductor type. Using a silver stranded cable might have lower resistance than a copper one, but if the amplifier you're using is introducing artifacts and noise particular to its design, there's very little point in delivering an extremely marginally higher voltage to it.

There are other considerations such as capacitance and inductance based on the construction of the cable. For example, a cable with high capacitance will act like a filter and attenuate higher frequencies; conductor type is only one factor.

If you only follow the marketing hype, you'll pay a premium price for something that might not perceptively improve anything, or at worst introduces *more* problems because of bad design. *(You could argue that a device or cable that noticeably alters an audio signal in some way is perceived as "better" by some people, because they like having some frequencies rolled off, but that's a discussion about subjective opinions.)*

Look for a cable of reasonable price from a reputable brand. If audio quality is your primary concern, obtain an expensive cable and have someone randomly swap it with a basic one. If you can reliably (better than chance) tell the difference in a blind test, then please report back!